# Building a Subquery using Protégé DL Query Editor

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl, ontology

I have

- a class "Document" with individuals DocA, DocB and DocC
- object property "about"
- a class "Watch" with individuals WatchA, WatchB and WatchC

I assert that DocA is about WatchA, DocB about WatchB, DocC about watchC

I need a query that returns all Documents about all existing watches. I could write a DL query: Document and (about value WatchA or about value WatchB or about value WatchC)

But I would like to write a subquery, ex. Watch hasColor Black - and get corresponding documents. So there are two steps:

1. a subquery that would be evaluated into a number of individuals (A, B),
2. and these individuals would be used for evaluating the first query: about value A or about value B

I am not using SPARQL, because it appears that inferences are not supported.

Any advice? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could formulate the OWL expression as: `Document and about some (Watch and color value black)`, and retrieve the individuals. In this case the query would return `documentA`, as it is the only one entailed by this expression.

I'm assuming your ontology/knowledge base look like the following (pseudo OWL Manchester syntax):

```
Prefix: example: <http://www.example.org/>

# Object properties
ObjectProperty: <example:about>
ObjectProperty: <example:color>

# Classes
Class: <example:Color>
Class: <example:Watch> 
Class: <example:Document>

# Individuals and their types
Individual: <example:black>
  Types: 
     <example:Color>

Individual: <example:watchA>
  Types: 
     <example:Watch>

  Facts:  
     <example:color>  <example:black>

Individual: <example:documentA>

  Types: 
     <example:Document>

  Facts:  
     <:example:about>  <example:watchA>
```